# How to hand " An unhandled exception occured." visual studio Xamarin Android?

Tags: visual-studio, exception, xamarin, xamarin.android

Sometimes a visual studio will not catch all Android error.

so I use the logcat inside visual studio

but it's somehow limited? is there and alternative

[image: logcat visual studio explain image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Open

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86\monitor.exe

If not available, install it for the SDK tool

2.Chose the device

3.Chose the logcat

4.R-Click on the logs and chose filter

5.Filter by the app name    and log tag AndroidRuntime

6.google the error

[image]